# Spark Context throwing 'error: identifier expected but '[' found.'

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am reading a book that says I should be able to type `sc.[\t]` and get a response. What I see is...

```
scala> sc.[\t]
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '[' found.
       sc.[\t]
          ^
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but ']' found.
       sc.[\t]
```

This is with spark 1.6.1 connecting to hadoop 2.7.2

The `sc` command seems to work...

```
scala> sc
res1: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@3cead673
```

P.S. I have never used Scala in my life.

Comment: The author probably means to say tab by [\t]. If you press the tab key, you will get suggestions on the available methods on sc.

Comment: Get a different book!

Comment: I have been marking up all the bugs in the book and I am only in the first chapter. Granted I am using 1.6 instead of 1.2. Is there a better advanced Spark book out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the author meant

```
scala> sc
```

When you press `tab`, you get

```
scala> sc
sc       scala    schema
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the book was expecting but I will post an update with that later.

Comment: You are correct sir... With a little caveat, it is in fact `sc.` then tab not `sc` to match the book.